# Let $c_{00}$ be the vsp over $\mathbb{C}$. $f = \sum_{i} x_i/i$, then prove that $\mid f \mid \leq \pi/ \sqrt(6)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

$c_{00}$ represets all complex sequence with finitely many non-zero terms. $f$ is map from $c_{00} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$, I have to find the norm of $f$.
Norm on $c_{00}$ is $\sum x_i\bar{y}_i$
My effort: If I consider the formula of sum of square, it's $n(n+1)(2n+1)/6$, and I was thinking maybe this $6$ is related to $\sqrt{6}$ of the question. Beyond this I don't know how to proceed.

Proof after comment: $\sum x_i/i < \sum 1/i$ because $\mid x \mid = 1$

Now $(\sum_{i}^{n} 1/i)^2 \leq \sum 1/i^2  = \pi^2/6$ because the cross term in the finite summation will be taken care by the term of form $1/i_1i_2$ in infinite sum. Now the result follows.

Comment: What norm are you using on $c_{00}$?

Comment: The $\sqrt 6$ almost certainly comes from the $6$ in the formula $$\sum_i \dfrac 1{i^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry I forgot to include the norm, I have updated it

Comment: The inequality $(\sum_1^n 1/i)^2 \le \sum 1/i^2$ is incorrect.